# Attempt to inject an AngularJS controller or service

Tags: angularjs

I have a `TreeListDataModel' factory in my AngularJS app which is used by a dashboard widget framework.

Now, I initially wanted to inject another service into `TreeListDataModel`; however, I have some important objects stored on `$rootScope` and/or `$scope`. So instead I've decided to inject a controller into `TreeListDataModel`.

PROBLEM: I cannot successfully inject my new `WidgetLinkingCtrl` into the `TreeListDataModel' factory.

My error is :

```
       Unknown provider: WidgetLinkingCtrlProvider <- WidgetLinkingCtrl <- TreeListDataModel <- widgetDefinitions
```

First thing I thought of is the order of my `index.html` file references, as follows :

You can see `dashboard-widget-controller.js` getting loaded before `gadgetDataModel.js`, yet I'm getting the injection error.

```html
<!-- dashboard-ui core -->
<script src="app/components/dashboard/dashboard-widget-defs.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/dashboard/dashboard-directives.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/dashboard/dashboard-widget-controller.js"></script> 

<!-- WIDGET-LINKING-CONTROLLER HERE !!! -->
<script src="app/components/widget-linking/widget-linking-controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/directives.js"></script>

<!-- factories -->

<!-- *** TreeListDataModel factory included in gadgetDataModel.js *** -->
<script src="app/components/data-model-factories/gadgetDataModel.js"></script>

<script src="app/components/data-model-factories/widgetModels.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/dashboard/kendo-refresh-factory.js"></script>

<!-- custom controllers -->
<script src="app/components/main/main-controller.js"></script>
```

here's the full `TreeListDataModel`:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp')
.factory('TreeListDataModel', function (WidgetDataModel, WidgetLinkingCtrl) {

function TreeListDataModel() {
}

TreeListDataModel.prototype = Object.create(WidgetDataModel.prototype);
TreeListDataModel.prototype.constructor = WidgetDataModel;

angular.extend(TreeListDataModel.prototype, {
  init: function () {
      // Kendo treelist is initialized in parseDataForTreeList() of gadget-settings-controller code

      var ds = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({  // init empty Kendo ds
   data: [],
   schema: {}
      });

      if (this.dataModelOptions.dataSource != undefined) {
   // some code omitted...
   this.dataModelOptions.dataSource = ds;
      }

      // KENDO TREELIST SELECT EVENT !!
      this.dataModelOptions.change = function (e) {
   var row = this.dataItem(this.select());
   
   var parentObj = _.find(this.dataItems(), { id: row.parentId });   
   //WidgetLinkingCtrl.linkCharts(row, parentObj);
      },
      // dataModelOptions are re-assigned in 'GridSettingsCtrl' controller, and persisted in 'DashboardState' factory
      this.updateScope(this.dataModelOptions);

  },
  updateScope: function (data) {
      this.dataModelOptions = data;
  },
  destroy: function () {
      WidgetDataModel.prototype.destroy.call(this);
  }
});

return TreeListDataModel;
});
```

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('rage')
      .controller('WidgetLinkingCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', 'kendoRefreshFactory', widgetLinking]);

    function widgetLinking($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, kendoRefreshFactory, widgetLinking) {

        function linkCharts(row, parentRow) {
            var r = $rootScope;
            if (parentRow == undefined) {
                // user clicked on root node of grid/treelist
            }

        }
    }
})();
```

Again, if you can help me figure out why I am getting the injection error when injecting `WidgetLinkingCtrl`, I would be grateful.

regards,

Bob

Answer (score 1):

In MVW approach, used in AngularJS, "controllers" control other (injectable) object. You can't inject controllers into services. However you can inject services intro controllers.

So in your example, one of possible solutions is to expose callback-hook and register your controller function in this hook.

TreeListDataModel:

```
this.dataModelOptions.change = function (e) {
  var row = this.dataItem(this.select());

  var parentObj = _.find(this.dataItems(), { id: row.parentId });     
  if (this.onChanged) this.onChanged(row, parentObj);
},
```

WidgetLinkingCtrl:

```
  function WidgetLinkingCtrl($scope, TreeListDataModel) {
     TreeListDataModel.onChanged = function(row, parentObj) {
       ... // do something 
    }
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
       TreeListDataModel.onChanged = nil; // don't forget to unregister controller, otherwise you can have memory leak
    }
  }
```

Thus, inverting dependency you can have same functionality as calling controller's method directly.

Comment: I cannot get it working. What I don't understand is how `WidgetLinkingCtrl` is going to capture your new `onChanged` event. I understand that you inject `TreeListDataModel` factory into the new controller, but when I select a treelist node and enter into the `.change` function, `this.onChanged` is always `undefined` . Am I not wiring up properly ? Here's a mockup plunker (but without the widget framework) - http://plnkr.co/edit/I6MJRx?p=preview

Comment: You need to make sure that controller is present somewhere in DOM. In your plnkr I don't see WidgetLinkingCtrl is used. If you'll put somewhere (or as controller of some directive or using `ng-controller`), controller will register itself in model